# Cakephp relation modes

Tags: cakephp

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Hospital' => array(
        'className' => 'Hospital',
        'foreignKey' => 'hospital_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);


public $hasMany = array(
    'Floor' => array(
        'className' => 'Floor',
        'foreignKey' => 'hospital_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

i have two tables hospitals and floors, i have retrieve data from hospital table and show in floor views in add floor.

Comment: what you want to do here

Answer (score 0):

You have already set up the relationship, so now you just need to create a controller action and a view.

Assuming your tables are in place, the easiest way to do this would simply be to run `cake bake all` on the Hospital model and Cake will generate the views for you. Cake is intelligent enough to generate a view that will show you a list of associated floors if that is what you want (it was unclear from your post).

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve the data from database like this...

```
mysql_select_db("users"); //your database name

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM langs"); //table name

$limit = 4;
$count = 3;

echo "<table border='1'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$name=$row['name'];
$email=$row['email'];
$contact=$row['contact'];
if($count < $limit){
echo "<tr>";
}

............. //you can put in table and in any other field
?>
```

Comment: This is a generic solution for PHP in general. The question (albeit a little unclear) asked for a CakePHP solution.